# Toolbar search with side menu

Tags: codenameone

When using the toolbar search feature, I encounter two issues.

The first (esthetical) problem is that when entering or leaving the search mode, the toolbar disappears for a moment, resulting in a flicker on the screen.

The second (functional) problem is that together with a side menu, the pointer dragged event results in a NullPointerException in the actionPerformed method on line 1302 of Toolbar.java. As a result, no scrolling is possible while in search mode.

Both problems can be replicated in the simulator and on Android using the form below.

Kind regards, Frans.

```
import com.codename1.ui.FontImage;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.TextArea;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;

public class ToolbarSearchForm extends Form
{
    public ToolbarSearchForm()
    {
        super("Toolbar search", new BorderLayout());
        getToolbar().addSearchCommand(e -> filter((String)e.getSource()));
        getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Settings", FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS, this::settingsAction);
        TextArea text = new TextArea(100, 100);
        text.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xFF000000); 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            sb.append(i + " Hello World!\n");
        }
        text.setText(sb.toString());
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, text);
    }

    private void filter(String filter)
    {
        System.out.println(filter);
    }

    private void settingsAction(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

The complete stack trace is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.ui.Toolbar$4.actionPerformed(Toolbar.java:1302)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:459)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:362)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerDragged(Form.java:3146)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2118)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1051)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:969)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.ui.Toolbar$4.actionPerformed(Toolbar.java:1302)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:459)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:362)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerDragged(Form.java:3146)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2118)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1051)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.flushEdt(Display.java:826)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.showModal(Form.java:2098)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showModal(Dialog.java:1137)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:582)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showPackedImpl(Dialog.java:1433)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showPacked(Dialog.java:1349)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showImpl(Dialog.java:1093)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1071)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1027)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:793)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:746)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:711)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:652)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:807)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:982)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

The getComponentForm() returns null (because the toolbar has no parent) in this line of Toolbar.java: `if (Display.getInstance().getImplementation().isScrollWheeling() || !enableSideMenuSwipe || getComponentForm().findCurrentlyEditingComponent() != null || getComponentForm().isEditing()) {`

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace of the exception?
I'm guessing the flickering you describe is the animation to flow in/out the search UI. Try switching on slow motion in the simulator to see whether that's the case and what's causing this. Also compare this on the device where it might look very different.

Comment: I added the stack trace to the question above. I also switched on slow motion (nice feature by the way), and when entering or leaving search mode, the original toolbar disappears immediately, and the new toolbar slowly drops down from the top. Is there a way to disable this animation?

Comment: I added the following code to the form with the search command: `@Override public void animateLayout(int duration) { revalidate(); }`. It solves the flickering issue. Is this a good way to solve this?

Comment: Not what I'd do but it would work and is unlikely to collide with other things at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a workaround for this issue in [this git commit](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/39f7379dc42589c10a45315244d0013a904bfb87). It should be in the update tomorrow.